# Get user location before useEffect in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a feature in my react-native app that fetches a list of data from an api based on the user's current location. I have a custom useLocation hook to get the user's location:

```
const useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const { granted } = await Location.getPermissionsAsync();
      if (!granted) {
        return Alert.alert(
          "Permissions needed",
          "This app does not currently have permission to access your location",
          [{ text: "Ok", style: "cancel" }]
        );
      }
      const {
        coords: { latitude, longitude },
      } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

      setLocation([longitude, latitude]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

Then in the Component that renders a FlatList of the data, in the useEffect hook, I have a simple http request to fetch the data that is near the user. The problem I am running into is that it seems when the useEffect hook is called and executes the http request, the useLocation hook has not finished executing so the location is undefined. Is there a way I can get the user's location before the http request is executed in the useEffect hook?

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

The external `useEffect` should have location as a dependency. If the `location` is `undefined` don't do anything. When the `location` is set, the component would re-render, and make the api call:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!location) return;
  
  /** make api call **/
}, [location]);
```

In addition, `getLocation` should be a dependency of the `useEffect` inside `useLocation`. Since you don't actually update the function, or even need it after the mount, declare and call it inside the `useEffect` block:

```
const useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLocation = async () => {
      try {
        const { granted } = await Location.getPermissionsAsync();
        if (!granted) {
          return Alert.alert(
            "Permissions needed",
            "This app does not currently have permission to access your location",
            [{ text: "Ok", style: "cancel" }]
          );
        }
        const {
          coords: { latitude, longitude },
        } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

        setLocation([longitude, latitude]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
  
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```